# Cordova not launching android app to emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, command-line-interface

[image]

Hi everyone,

I am running an example cordova app on platform android with command:

```
cordova run android
```

The command line gets stuck on 
"........................." and keeps continuing.

When I run with:

```
 cordova run android --verbose
```

I get the following:

> Running adb shell command "ps" on target emulator-5554... Running
>   command: D:\android-sdk\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   emulator-5554 shell ps Command finished with error code 0:
>   D:\android-sdk\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -s,emulator-5554,shell,ps

As you can see my emulator is already up and running. What can I do to solve this issue, I have tried answers from other slackoverflow similar questions, but it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: I could not find the answer either - but doing a "cold boot" of the emulator from AVD fixed it for me (at least it allowed me to move forward).